# Apply Same JS Script to Several File Upload Fields

Tags: javascript, input

I have a form with 3 separate file-upload fields.  I also have a JS script to show an image preview whenever a file is added.  The script works great.  My problem is, I want it to run on each of the 3 upload fields so they all have preview images.  Obviously, don't want to write the same script 3 times, but not sure how to apply the same script to multiple input fields.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="form_box_item">
    <input type='file' id="input1" />
    <p><img id="image1" src="#" height="60" width="80" alt="" /></p>
</div>

<div class="form_box_item">
    <input type='file' id="input2" />
    <p><img id="image2" src="#" height="60" width="80" alt="" /></p>
</div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image1').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#input1").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Here's my script running as a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewschenker/hvmVJ/11/)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing that I notice is that your target image has an id that's almost the same as the source input element - one just has to replace "input" with "image". I.e input1 -> image1, input2 -> image2

Next thing I notice, is that your `reader.onload` function currently targets a specific element - #image1. I also note that the input to the `readURL` function is the input element itself.

With these things in mind, we can change the `onload` function so that it:

- gets the id of the element that triggered its call
- replace "input" with "image" in this id string
- use this computed id string to target the correct image.

Once implemented, a complete example appears thusly:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script>

function readURL(input) 
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0])
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) 
        {
            var imgId = input.id.replace("input", "image");
            $("#"+imgId).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
}

window.addEventListener('load', myInit, false);

// target 2 input elements explicitly
//function myInit()
//{
//  $("#input1").change( onFileInputChanged );
//  $("#input2").change( onFileInputChanged );
//}

// target all inputs of type=file
function myInit()
{
    $(':file').each(
        function(){ 
                $(this).change( onFileInputChanged ) 
        } 
    );
}


function onFileInputChanged(evt)
{
    readURL(this);
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form_box_item">
        <input type='file' id="input1" />
        <p><img id="image1" src="#" height="60" width="80" alt="" /></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form_box_item">
        <input type='file' id="input2" />
        <p><img id="image2" src="#" height="60" width="80" alt="" /></p>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvmVJ/16/

Comment: This looks great!  Thanks for helping.  Just one other question: is it possible to further reduce the "$("#input1"), "$("#input2")" ... references?  For example, if I have 10 input fields, I would need to list out all 10 explicitly?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helps. I'd just tried to keep the code short and sweet for the given html. There's always a break-even point for doing things in a loop or explicitly. For me, I think that point would be about 3 elements in this instance. With 10 elements, I too would prefer to use a loop. With that in mind, you could use the alternate myInit function I've just added to the solution.

Comment: Just realized one other minor issue.  In Chrome and Safari, there is a "broken image" below the input field before an image is chosen.  This is not a problem in Firefox.  What would be the best way to solve that issue?  Thanks again!

Comment: I guess you could approach that in a number of ways. The one that I'd probably be inclined to take would be to create a 1px x 1px transparent png image. I'd set the source of the element to that in the html, also setting the source of the image element to the same pic if the user pressed the cancel button in the file-selection dialog.